# Image field not updating after editing the product in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-forms

I am following an Angular tutorial, when I create product everything works, when I updated the product everything works except that the image doesn't get updated. Here is what goes wrong:

- Image doesn't get updated when you attempt to change the image.
- Old image that was there also disappears when you "update" and save the product.

Here is how it shows on the front-end, you can see the empty src

[image]

Here is my TS file (relevant part)

```
  imageDisplay: any | any[];
  //imageDisplay!: string | ArrayBuffer; //this was giving an error
  currentProductId!: string;

    private _checkEditMode() {
      this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['id']) {
          this.editMode = true;
          this.currentProductId = params['id'];
          this.productsService
            .getProduct(params['id'])
            .subscribe((product) => {
              ....
              this.imageDisplay = product.image; //I THINK THIS LINE IS THE CULPRIT?
              this.form.controls['image'].setValidators([]);
              this.form.controls['image'].updateValueAndValidity();
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

EDIT: here is the HTML code:

```
 <div>
   <label form="name">Main image</label><br>
    <input type="file" class="p-inputtext mt-2" accept="image/*" (change)="onImageUpload($event)" /><br> 
     <div class="col-2 mt-2 pl-0"> 
      <img style="width:100%;" [src] = "imageDisplay" alt="">
       <small *ngIf="form.controls['image'].invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error">Image is required</small>

    </div>
   </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: product.image must be undefined. Please add your html file also.

Comment: Thanks @Gokul , I just did.

Comment: Can you just console the **product** ? there might be the chances of product.image being null or undefined.
Try this to debug:  
**this.imageDisplay = product.image || "http://placehold.it/200x200"**

Comment: Thanks Sachin, this works:  **this.imageDisplay = ` http://placehold.it/200x200 `** ... what should I do now?

Comment: @sachin any guidance on how to define product.image? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your src. `<img style="width:100%;" [src] = "imageDisplay" alt="">`   `<img style="width:100%;" [src]="imageDisplay" alt="">` you got space between your code. In your image you can see that src is not being loaded in your html.

Comment: Thanks. But that is probably not it since the issue only happens when uodating an existing product, not when you create a product. And two experts have pointed out that my image.source isn't defined and I don't know how to define it, so that's probably the issue